# C# Access Modifiers : restrict some methods to only one other class

Tags: c#

Kind of a noobie question but I'm curious and I can't find an answer to my question:

I have:

```
public class Profile
{
public void methodA(){}
}

public class User
{
private List<Profile> listProfiles;
public void test() { App.Handler.doA(listProfiles[0]);} //let's say we have 1 profile
}

public class Handler
{
public void doA(Profile) { profile.methodA();}
}
```

I want to restrict the use of methodA() to only my Handler Class, is it possible via a key word or some other way?

The purpose is to have everything going through the Handler.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to nest `Handler` inside the `Profile` class and the you can make `methodA` private.

Comment: Perfect! I would have learnt something today.
Thank you leppie.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using standard means. You can use workarounds:

- nest classes in one and then use private keys.
- use separate assembly for such classes and restrict usage by internal keyword